# Traefik v2 listen on port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, traefik

I am using **Traefik v2** with Docker Swarm. I want to achieve the following routing:

1. mydomain.com:9000 -> Traefik dashboard
2. mydomain.com:5000 -> my application

**docker-compose-traefik.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:5000"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9000:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

networks:
  traefik-net:
    external:
      name: traefik-net
```

**docker-compose-whoami.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  whoami:
    image: "jwilder/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"

networks:
  traefik-net:
    external:
      name: traefik-net
```

`jwilder/whoami` exposes port 8000 in its [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/whoami/dockerfile). I want to redirect port 5000 (my entrypoint defined in docker-compose-traefik.yml) to port 8000 in container.

I created network `traefik-net` with: `docker network create -d bridge traefik-net`.

I deployed both stacks with:

1. `docker-stack deploy -c docker-compose-traefik.yml Traefik`
2. `docker-stack deploy -c docker-compose-whoami.yml Whoami`

When I visit mydomain.com:9000 it opens Traefik dashboard as it should. When I visit mydomain.com:5000 it says that "This site can’t be reached".

My question is: **How to redirect request to port 5000 (mydomain.com:5000) to port 8000 inside whoami container?**

Comment: you need to map also the port 5000:8000 in the compose, or use a reverse proxy

Comment: If I map the port in the docker-compose-whoami, wouldn't the request bypass Traefik and go directly to container?

Comment: that is right, I am not too much in Traefik, but there should be away to redirect that using its configuration. see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-centos-7

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else having similar problems, I found a solution. I needed to change **ports section** in docker-compose-traefik.yml from

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "9000:8080"
```

to

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "9000:8080"
  - "5000:5000" <-- add this
```

Hope this helps someone. :)